# When is it mandatory to call qRegisterMetaType()?

Tags: qt

I have studied the qt documentation of [qRegisterMetaType()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1) where it says that this function must be called before the corresponding type can be used in signal/slot mechanism. However I couldn't find any code example where this has to be done by hand.

[This](https://woboq.com/blog/qmetatype-knows-your-types.html) page states, that the registration is done automatically by the moc if it can determine that the type may be registered as meta-type. It looks like this is right, because I tested QSignalSpy, QObject::connect() (direct and queued connection) and QVariant - with just using Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(type) and none of them needed a explicit call to qRegisterMetaType to work.

So my question is: when do I have to call qRegisterMetaType(), because otherwise the code won't work?

Answer (score 0):

The Qt docs say that [Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) is necessary in case one has a connect being a queued connection.

> Adding a Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() makes the type known to all template
>   based functions, including QVariant. Note that if you intend to use
>   the type in queued signal and slot connections or in QObject's
>   property system, you also have to call qRegisterMetaType() since the
>   names are resolved at runtime.

For this I build a small testing app, that exemplifies the behavior.

Just try to remove the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Message)` and watch the warnings and output change. In case of the normal connect the macro seems to be unnecessary.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include "MyHeaderView.h"

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Message);

int main(int argc, char **args)
{
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    {
        TestObject sender;
        TestObject receiver;
        QObject::connect(&sender, &TestObject::sendMessage, &receiver, &TestObject::onMessage);
        sender.emitMessage(1, 2);
    }


    // This requires Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Message);
    QThread workerThread;
    TestObject sender2;
    TestObject receiver2;
    receiver2.moveToThread(&workerThread);
    workerThread.start();
    QObject::connect(&sender2, &TestObject::sendMessage, &receiver2, &TestObject::onMessage, Qt::ConnectionType::QueuedConnection);
    sender2.emitMessage(3, 4);

    app.exec();
}
```

**TestObject.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

struct Message
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

class TestObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void emitMessage(int x, int y) { emit sendMessage(Message{ x,y }); }
    signals:
        void sendMessage(const Message&);

public slots:
    void onMessage(const Message& m) { qDebug() << m.x << m.y; }
};
```

Comment: I know about Q_DECLARE_METATYPE but the actual question was, in which circumstances it is necessary to call qRegisterMetaType(). Both QSignalSpy and QObject::connect() work without calling qRegisterMetaType(). So when do I have to do that?

Comment: Thanks for your example. I admit that this is new to me, I thought that Q_DECLARE_METATYPE is necessary for any connection not just queued ones. Unfortunately this still does not answer when qRegisterMetatype must be called by the user. I'm asking this, because we have code where calls to qRegisterMetatype are all over the place. If they are not actually needed, we could clean up the code. As your example shows, it works without any call to qRegisterMetatype, because connect does this by itself. So why is qRegisterMetatype even there and not an internal Qt function, if it's done automatically?